# ¿Override en una clase heredada guardando su contenido?

Tags: c#

¿Cómo hacer *override* de un método guardando la implementación del padre en C#?

Estoy intentado hacer una clase secundaria que añada contenido a ese método principal, pero al hacer un Override borra todo el contenido de el método padre y lo reemplaza por el contenido del hijo.

¿Hay alguna forma de que en la clase "B" añada el código de la clase "A" + El código escrito en la clase B?

```
public abstract class A{
   public virtual void foo(){
      Console.WriteLine("One");
   }
}

public class B : A{
   public override void foo(){
      //Save implementation 
      //Console.WriteLine("One")
      Console.WriteLine("And Two");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > ¿Hay alguna forma de que en la clase "B" añada el código de la clase "A" + El código escrito en la clase B?

No.

Simplemente usa la palabra clave [base](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/base) para poder invocar un método de la clase base.

Código en C#:

```cs
public class B : A
{
   public override void foo()
   {
      base.foo(); //Invoca al método de la clase padre
      Console.WriteLine("And Two");
   }
}
```

Por pantalla debería salir:

```cs
One
And Two
```